# Menu items shloud specify a title error and icon not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I am trying to add a shopping cart icon with the code below the output I get is two options namely create order and order in settings, and Icon is nowhere to be seen.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

**My code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="order" />
    <item
        android:title="@string/create_order"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your xmlns android schema is wrong. you have written this :

```
xmlns:android= "https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

instead of this write this :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="order" />
    <item
        android:title="@string/create_order"
        android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_album"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: Sorry Dude didn't work out. Is it possible that error is not here but somewhere else...

Comment: The error "Menu items should specify a title" is gone, but icon is still not there...

Comment: create-order is showing inside the settings list(at top right), but not the icon

Comment: i am able to put an image, but not icons on the bar

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the showAsAction attribute to never, then these menu items will never show as action views. Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <menu   xmlns:android= "https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <item   android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
           android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            />
        <item
            android:title="@string/create_order"
            android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          />
</menu>
```